# Getting spark-submit to work

Tags: macos, apache-spark

I am trying to get spark-submit to work after downloading the prebuilt for hadoop 2.4 package to my mac. I've been running PySpark against it just fine for a while, but when I set up some java code to hit Spark via an exec of spark-submit, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "spark-submit": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at net.skai.functions.spark.SkaiSparkSubmit.runSparkSubmit(SkaiSparkSubmit.java:43)
    at net.skai.functions.spark.SkaiSparkDriver.ingestBatch(SkaiSparkDriver.java:167)
    at net.skai.functions.spark.SparkFuncFramework.ripDataAndExecuteFunctions(SparkFuncFramework.java:64)
    at net.skai.core.internal.PipelineUtilImpl.ripDataAndExecuteFunctions(PipelineUtilImpl.java:204)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 15 more
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `~/.bash_profile` and then reload your bash profile in terminal with `source ~/.bash_profile`.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
```

If you are running your code from within an IDE (Intellij, Eclipse, ...) you will likely need to restart your IDE and potentially your computer to load your changes to `$PATH`.